# Overlay density plot to each existing facet wrapped density plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a dataframe with ~37000 rows that contains 'name' in string format and 'UTCDateTime' in posixct format and am using it to produce a facet wrapped density plot of time grouped by the names:

[image]

I also have a separate density plot of posixct datetime data from an entirely different dataframe:

[image]

I want to overlay this second density plot on each individual facet_wrapped plot in the first density plot. Is there a way to do that? In general, if I have plots of any kind that are facet wrapped and another plot of the same type but different data that I want to overlay on each facet of the facet wrap, how do I do so?

Comment: Ooh, teunbrand's answer shows my knowledge was out of date! Deleting my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should in theory be as simple as not having the column that you're facetting by in the second dataframe. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(data = faithful,
               aes(x = eruptions)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: To get the densities on the same scale for the two types of data, you can use the computed variables using `after_stat()`*:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(scaled),
                   fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(data = faithful,
               aes(x = eruptions,
                   y = after_stat(scaled))) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

* Prior to ggplot2 v3.3.0 also `stat(variable)` or `...variable...`.

Comment: This worked, but they were too different in scale so I decided to add the data as another facet wrap. Thanks!

Comment: You could use the computed variables from `geom_density()` too, see the edit

Comment: That seems useful, but I want to preserve the separate scales to best represent them. Thanks anyway!