# How to facet-wrap comparative density plots in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, comparison, density-plot

I have a dataset of different conditions with values of length.
I can make histograms/density plots out of it and can facet wrap it for comparison to the control condition.

I can also make individual plots comparing the control to a specific condition (i.e. overlapping density plot with transparency). This helps me see the distribution of values for each condition compared to the control.

However, I would like to see the comparison for all conditions side by side such as when I use facetwrap.

For example, if this is my data in a dataset "test":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmLNY.png)

This is how I made the density plot facet wrap:

```
test %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Size, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Condition))
```

This is my individual overlapped density plot (I create a new data set that only contains the 2 conditions I want to compare):

```
test_compare <- test %>% 
  filter(Condition == "Control" | Condition == "Condition 1")
test_compare %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Size, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

Where the two overlap like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL1Nb.png)

I would like to have a grid where I can see each condition compared to the control. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623348/how-to-use-facet-to-create-multiple-density-plot-in-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380055/overlay-density-plot-to-each-existing-facet-wrapped-density-plot-in-ggplot2

Comment: I think @MrFlick's [_second_ link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63380055/3358272) is more likely the link you need, as it superimposes a single-level of data over all other levels.

Comment: FYI, `filter(Condition == "Control" | Condition == "Condition 1")` can more succinctly and more generally be written as `filter(Condition %in% c("Control", "Condition 1"))`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is essentially what is linked in the comments by @MrFlick

You should be able to create a second dataframe with the "control" data and add a second `geom_density()` call to add the control data independently of whatever gets faceted.

Reproducible Example since you didn't provide any data.

```
dat <- data.frame(Size = 0:100)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(Condition = case_when(Size >= 75 ~ "C1", 
                               Size >= 50 & Size < 75 ~ "C2",
                               Size >= 25 & Size < 50 ~ "C3",
                               Size >= 0 & Size < 25 ~ "Control",
                               TRUE ~ "NA"), 
         Control = case_when(str_detect(Condition, "Control") ~ "Control",
                             TRUE ~ "Sample"))

dat.control <- dat %>%
  select(Size, Control)

ggplot(dat %>% filter(Condition != "Control"), aes(x = Size)) +
  geom_density(data = dat.control %>% filter(Control == "Control"), aes(x = Size), alpha = 0.2, fill = "orange") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2, aes(fill = Condition)) +
  facet_wrap(~Condition)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Next time I will add a small data example

Comment: fyi, some consider answering a question that has been identified (but not yet closed) as a duplicate is poor form and may downvote accordingly (I will not). I suspect the question can (and arguably should) be closed, since the premise of duplicates is mostly sound. While my personal take is that providing an answer helps the OP, and providing the dupe-links as more examples helps gives the OP some different context, some may downvote to discourage it. This is a worthy answer, though it's always good to include non-base (`stringr` is new here, in addition to the implied `dplyr`+`ggplot2`).